# Apache Tomcat-javax.servlet.ServletException: My Class is not a Servlet

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, spring-boot, web.xml

Currently I develop a web application with Spring MVC and Spring Boot.

I was trying to package a spring boot application as a war. I modified my Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication  
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AuditConfigurationApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(AuditConfigurationApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuditConfigurationApplication.class, args);
    }
```

-The pom.xml file :

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 

        <!-- spring data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <!-- pdfbox -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
           <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
           <version>2.0.1</version>
          </dependency>

   <!-- itextpdf -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
           <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
           <version>5.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>

    <!-- mysql-connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.11</version>
</dependency>

      <!-- Spring security  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>

        <!-- ecj for exception "No Java compiler available"  -->
       <dependency>
             <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
             <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

        <!-- for uri:  -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
         <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
     <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.2</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
     </dependency>     
   <!-- For JSON Object -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

-My controller Rest:

```
package com.SSC.Services.REST;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Employees")
public class UtilisateursRestController {

@RequestMapping(value="/ALL", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Users> AllUsers(){
    return UM.listeT();
    }

}
```

- web.xml `version="3.1"`:

> ```
> <!-- ====================================================== -->
>   <!--  2. Define servlet with private context               -->
>   <!-- ===================================================== -->
>   <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>audit</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
>     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
>   </servlet>
>   <!-- ===================================================== -->
>   <!-- One servlet, the audit, to rule it all           -->
>   <!-- ===================================================== -->
>   <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>audit</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
>   </servlet-mapping>
>
>  <servlet>
>         <servlet-name>Users</servlet-name>
>         <servlet-class>com.SSC.Services.REST.UtilisateursRestController</servlet-class>
>     </servlet> 
>     <servlet-mapping>
>         <servlet-name>Users</servlet-name>
>         <url-pattern>/Employees/*</url-pattern> //URL of controller REST
>     </servlet-mapping>
>
> <error-page>
>  <error-code>404</error-code>
>  <location>/404</location>
> </error-page>
> ```

-audit-servlet.xml :

```
<beans>
<!-- register controller in servlet private context -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.SSC.Services.REST"/>  

</beans>
```

-I export my Project "Apps" as war-file into "C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.15\webapps\". Tomcat creates folder "Apps", which contains everything:

```
Apps
  --META-INF
     -maven
     -MANIFEST.MF
     -war-tracker
  --WEB-INF
      -classes
           -com
           -static
           -application.properties
      - lib-provided
      -lib
      - web.xml + audit-servlet.xml
  --org
  -- My JSP pages ..
```

When I access a API REST: `http://95.x.x.x/Apps(Name of floder)/Employees/ALL` , I have this error message:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Class [com.SSC.Services.REST.UtilisateursRestController] is not a Servlet
>    Apache Tomcat / 8.5.15

How to fix this problem?

Thank you,

Comment: UtilisateursRestController is not a servlet. You are tried to map a controller to a servlet , it throws exception.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, But how to solve this problem @VNT? How to ensure access to my REST API?

Comment: Remove the `web.xml` and please read the pretty well documentation [section on how to create a deployable war](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) of the reference guide (your dependencies are a bit messy in that regard).

Comment: How to do the servlet mapping? If you delete the `web.xml`  @M. Deinum

Comment: You are using Spring Boot, use that to do the mapping. Also you aren't mapping a servlet you are mapping a controller...

Comment: (unrelated to the question) PDFBox is at 2.0.6 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `web.xml` is the main culprit here and as a second contender your dependencies. See also the Spring Boot Reference Guide, which has a nice section on [creating a deployable war](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file). You might want to take a look at the [war sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-traditional/pom.xml) on GitHub as well.

First remove your `web.xml` you don't need it. Your `AuditConfigurationApplication` is also `SpringBootServletInitializer` which takes care of bootstrapping the application in a servlet container (instead of being executable).

Next your dependencies are also a bit flaky. You should use the `spring-boot-starter-security` instead of manually define the Spring Security dependencies. And you should use another dependency for the embedded library.

```
<!-- Spring security  -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You should make the following provided

```
<!-- Provided (for embedded war support) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Judging by your dependencies you are also using JSP (although I would recommend to use something like Thymeleaf nowadays) you might want to read the [JSP Limitations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations) section in the reference guide and take a look at the needed dependencies in the [JSP sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp) on GitHub.

You don't need the `servlet-api` dependency that is already included in the `spring-boot-starter-web`.